# Configuring a custom log file for iptables

Tags: debian, logs, iptables, rsyslog

I'm trying to log dropped packages to a custom file instead of `/var/log/messages`.

To achieve this, I have added these two lines at the end of my configuration file:

```
    -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-INPUT-Dropped: " --log-level 4
    -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-OUTPUT-Dropped: " --log-level 4
```

This works because I have configured the INPUT and OUTPUT chains as DROP by default, so if the package does not meet any previous rule, it will be logged and dropped.

However, I cannot log them to a custom file. They log successful to `/var/log/messages`, but I want them to be logged on `/var/log/iptables.log`. I've created the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf` with the following content:

```
    :msg, contains, "IPTables-INPUT-Dropped: " - /var/log/iptables.log
    & ~
```

then I restarted rsyslog, `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart` and sent some packages I knew were going to be dropped.However, they are not logged in iptables.log, they are still being logged on `/var/log/messages`.

Which configuration is missing?

**SOLVED**
The problem is that there shouldn't be an space between **-** and **/**

Comment: That should work (I use it).  However, I have it in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` before other directives, so that the message gets dropped before anything else picks it up. Try that and `kill -HUP \`pidof rsyslogd\``.  Maybe loose the space at the end of the quoted string.

Comment: I've added the first line to rsyslog.conf but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there shouldn't be a space between - and /

Answer (score 3):

This can be possible using :

To disable iptables logs in syslog , do modification as below in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none;kern.*=!kern.warning             -/var/log/syslog
```

To log in separate file; append :

```
kern.=warning -/var/log/iptables.log
```

then once restart `syslog` or `rsyslog` and `tail` the logs

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
```

It's works in `syslog` and `rsyslog` also

Answer (score 2):

This is a an alternative approach using `ulogd`. I would suggest this mechanism as it stops the kernel logging mechanism `-m LOG` uses (which has the grievous side effect of filling your `dmesg` log as well).

First you'll need ulogd, which you can get with an `apt-get install ulogd`. Edit your `/etc/ulogd.conf`, enable this module (by removing the `#` at the start of the line):

```
plugin="/usr/lib/ulogd/ulogd_LOGEMU.so"
```

and change/add the section `[LOGEMU]`:

```
[LOGEMU]
file="/var/log/iptables.log"
sync=1
```

And then restart your ulogd with `/etc/init.d/ulogd restart`. Then instead of `-j LOG` use `-j ULOG` on your iptables rules. The ULOG module has no concept of `--log-level` so you can remove those options. It also uses `--ulog-prefix` instead of `--log-prefix`.

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: Did you restart the ulogd after adding the entry? (`/etc/init.d/ulogd restart` as root)

Comment: yeah, of course. Actually it is ulogd2 rather than ulogd

Comment: ah you need another step will add it to the answer.

Comment: Nop, it comes enabled by default.

Comment: That's definitely all that is needed for ULOG to work, are you sure some earlier rule is not stopping it reaching the `-j ULOG line`? I tend to put my ULOG rules with matching rules as the following `-j DENY` rule (where I want to log those DENY's of course).

Comment: I'm pretty sure, in fact they are being logged successful on `/var/log/messages` if I don't use ulog. Using ulog, they are not (as you pointed out)

Comment: Very strange, I've just gone through that setup on a vanilla Debian install and it is working (deny's logged to /var/log/iptables.log and dmesg saved of being spammed). Does moving the rule further up the ruleset make it log?

Comment: You might of missed this because I added it as an edit to my previous comment: Does moving the rule further up the ruleset  (i.e something like rule 1) make it log?

Comment: If I put it the rule #1, it will log everything, not just dropped packets.My setup is: INPUT/OUTPUT default to DROP -> then a couple of rules accepting some packets -> and finally the logging rules. On this way, if a packet is not accepted by any rules, it will end up on the logging rule and then dropped.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, I'm just wondering if you have a rule in amongst your "couple of rules" that DROP and so it's not getting as far the `-j ULOG`.

Comment: I just fixed it, the problem was the `- /var/log/iptables.log`, there shouldn't be a space between - and /

Comment: @Drav Sloan: your method works perfectly on Raspbian too

Answer (score 2):

**FYI:**

`& ~` is deprecated in the new rsyslog, you should use `stop` instead.

**/etc/rsyslog.d/10-iptables**

```
if ( $msg contains 'IN=' and $msg contains 'OUT=' ) 
then { 
    /var/log/10-iptables.log
    stop
}
```

**/etc/logrotate.d/iptables**

```
/var/log/iptables.log
{
        rotate 30
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress

        postrotate
                service rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

Note i set the prefix to 10- to catch it before it reach the default rules (50-defaults).

Answer (score 0):

A working solution with ulogd

a)Ensure you have this module on start

```
modprobe nf_log_ipv4
cp /etc/modules /etc/modules.bak
echo nf_log_ipv4 >> /etc/modules
```

b)edit the file /etc/ulogd.conf
enable those plugin(uncomment #)

```
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_inppkt_NFLOG.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_IFINDEX.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_IP2STR.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_filter_PRINTPKT.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_output_LOGEMU.so"
plugin="/usr/lib64/ulogd/ulogd_raw2packet_BASE.so"
```

add this line before the first commented # stack

```
stack=firewall11:NFLOG,base1:BASE,ifi1:IFINDEX,ip2str1:IP2STR,print1:PRINTPKT,emu11:LOGEMU
```

and finally at the end of file add those lines

```
[firewall11]
group=11

[emu11]
file="/var/log/iptables.log"
sync=1
```

c)
Now, I prefer to use old method of iptables script instead of firewalld, in my iptables script I use those lines for logging.

```
# Log
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A FORWARD -j NFLOG
iptables -A LOGGING -j NFLOG --nflog-prefix "[firewall-drop]:" --nflog-group 11
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

d) the final parts

```
touch /var/log/iptables.log
systemctl restart ulogd
```

Verify if work with this command

```
tail -f /var/log/iptables.log
```

You should see some lines after an event: nmap portscan, or simply telnet to your machine(hope is disabled or firewalled).