# What's the difference between ULOG and NFLog?

Tags: linux, iptables, logs

Various places suggest to use ULOG or NFLOG instead of LOG for getting dedicated netfilter logging (see for example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89001/39664) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129028/39664)).

From looking at `man iptables` those two look quite alike. Except that NFLOG talks about some "nfnetlink_log backend" while ULOG doesn't talk about any backend.

1. What's the difference?
2. Are there typical situations for using one or the other?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ULOG` was the original user space logging added in Kernel 2.4 for ipv4.

`NFLOG` is the newer, generic (layer3 independent) logging framework for 2.6 kernels based on the original ULOG but implemented via [libnfnetlink](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnfnetlink/index.html)

Both will send logs to [`ulogd`](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/ulogd/) which will then log via whatever output plugin you choose.

Use `ULOG` if you are stuck with `ulogd-1.x` as 1.x might not play nicely with `NFLOG`. You really should be using `ulogd-2.x` as `1.x` is considered legacy and is EOL.

Otherwise, just use `NFLOG`

Comment: Note that ulogd 1.24 (as shipped on Debian/stable) doesn't seem to like NFLOG, but seems to like ULOG.

Comment: ah debian.. always so stable =) added a note to the A. Also jessie will be moving to ulogd-2.x

Comment: Is there any way to detect which one a system is capable of using so that a wrapper script can always use the right one?

Comment: @user1169420, maybe like this: `if ulogd --version | grep -q 'Version 2'; then (use NFLOG); else (use ULOG); fi`

Comment: And what about the regular `LOG`?, what relation does it hold against the others?.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel `LOG` writes to the kernel log, so is grouped in with the other kernel logging and can take over the ring buffer if you are logging a lot. Generally this will go to the journal/syslog where you can forward it to other targets.  `NFLOG` allows you to manage the iptables logging/targets outside of the kernel route